Wintson logs undefined in production env
Here's my logging class. Everything works perfect on development env. As soon as I set NODE_ENV=production - winston ignores any message passed and just prints "undefined" to the log file
import winston from 'winston';
import path from 'path';
import DailyRotateFile from 'winston-daily-rotate-file';

export class Logger {
  private static _instance: Logger;
  private logger: winston.Logger;
  private rotateFileConfig = {
    datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    zippedArchive: true,
    maxSize: '20m',
    maxFiles: '14d',
  };

  private infoTransport: DailyRotateFile = new DailyRotateFile({
    level: 'info',
    filename: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'logs', '%DATE%.info.log'),
    ...this.rotateFileConfig,
  });

  private constructor() {
    this.logger = winston.createLogger({});

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      this.logger.add(
        new winston.transports.Console({
          format: winston.format.combine(
            winston.format.colorize(),
            winston.format.simple(),
          ),
        }),
      );
    } else {
      this.logger.add(this.infoTransport);
    }

    this.logger.on('error', (err) => {
      console.error('Logger error:', err);
    });
  }

  static getInstance() {
    if (this._instance) {
      return this._instance;
    }

    this._instance = new Logger();
    return this._instance;
  }

  public async logInfo(message: string) {
    this.logger.log({
      level: 'info',
      message: message,
    });
  }
}

Undefined is being logged on production env:

